# What is the Mac OS X equivalent of extracting the device file for the recently plugged in USB memory stick from dmesg in Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, usb, macos

For more context: I have this command to put in a document showing how to write an ISO directly into the most recently plugged in USB memory stick in Linux:

```
dd if=image.iso of=$(echo /dev/$(dmesg | tail | awk '/sd.:/ { print $3 }' | awk -F ':' '{ print $1 }'))
```

How would it have to be changed to accomplish the same result in Mac OS X?